# Which Version of Netbeans is more appropriate with JDK 10.0.1

Tags: java, jdk, netbeans

I've Ubuntu 18.04 installed and I've installed **JDK-10.0.1** as well. Previously I installed **Netbeans**-8.2 and it didn't work. After some research I realize that **Netbeans**-8.2 is not compatible with **JDK-10.0.1**.
I want to use **Netbeans** for **JAVA development**. 
Which version of Netbeans will be compatible with JDK-10.0.1? And where to get?

Comment: Just note that NetBeans is no longer owned by Oracle. It is now owned by the Apache Foundation. You can updated versions from now on from here: https://netbeans.apache.org/

Comment: JDK 8 is also required for Apache NetBeans 9.0.

Comment: They said: JDK 8 is required.. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK 8 is required for installing and running both NetBeans IDE 8.2 and Apache NetBeans 9.0.

The Eclipse snap package from the default Ubuntu repositories is perfect for Java programming because it is bundled with a Java development environment. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install eclipse --classic
```

This command will install the latest Photon Release 4.8 version of Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. Eclipse Photon JDT supports Java 10. Eclipse changed its codename policy so that Eclipse releases from September 2018 and onward are named after the year and month of the release date, for example Eclipse 2020-06. This naming scheme also applies to the eclipse snap package.

[image]
<sup>**Select Java version from Installed JREs in Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences**</sup>

To go through the built-in tutorials in Eclipse Photon select *Help* -> *Welcome* -> *Tutorials*.

Comment: so eclipse will work with JDK 10?

Comment: I added a screenshot to show that openjdk-11-jdk (JDK version 10.0.2+13) from the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories is installed. Eclipse Photon works with this version.

Comment: Got it thanks!
Actually I was using **Netbeans** on **Windows** for long time. How much it would be difficult to work with **Eclipse**

Comment: To go through the built-in tutorials in Eclipse Photon select *Help* -> *Welcome* -> *Tutorials*. That will get you started working with Eclipse.

Comment: So, now I think it's time to change IDE